# Как сделать дату в django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, время, datetime

Только начал изучать Django. Пытаюсь сделать показ времени в темплейте.

Пишу это во views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import datetime

def main_view(request):
   a = datetime.datetime.now()
   return render(request, 'templates/main/index.html', {'dat': a})
```

Это в index.html

```
    {% for foo in dat %}
    <p>{{ foo|date:"D d M Y" }}<p>
    {% endfor %}
```

Время не выводит.
Расскажите что да как)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не нужно его итерировать циклом `for`.
Достаточно выводить его как переменную с шаблонным фильтром `|date`:

```
# index.html
{{dat|date:"D d M Y"}}
```

или если захотите отделить дату и время

```
# index.html
{{ dat|date:"D d M Y" }} {{ dat|time:"H:i" }}
```